# Copy file name without extension in Vifm

Tags: xclip, vifm

From the the [Vifm wiki](https://wiki.vifm.info/index.php/How_to_copy_path_to_current_file/directory_to_system_clipboard) and using [xclip](https://github.com/astrand/xclip), they show how to copy the filename of a selected file:

```
nnoremap yn :!echo -n %c | xclip -selection clipboard %i<cr>:echo expand('%"c') "is yanked to clipboard"<cr>
```

But it copies it with the extension, how can I copy the name of a file without it's extension to the clipboard?

Comment: The secret is to realise that there is not extension: file-name extensions where is CPM. And MS-Windows. However they don't exist in Unix or NT. The dot and the rest of the name, is just part of the name. However you can use the `basename` tool to remove them (or at least what looks like one).

Comment: Note your code have many bugs, you need to use the quotes. E.g. `<` and `>` have special meaning in the shell. You will get some very unexpected behavior.

Comment: from the `basename` man page: "Print NAME with any leading directory components removed.  If specified, also remove a trailing SUFFIX."

Comment: `basename "$(basename "$fileName" .sh)" .txt` — OK this dose not scale to any "extension". — use `sed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sed to remove everything after and including the first dot:

```
:nnoremap yn :!sed "s/\..*//"<<<%c|xclip -selection clipboard %i<cr>
```

If your shell does not support herestrings (`<<<`), use printf
([Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)) to pipe into sed:

```
:nnoremap yn :!printf '%%s' %c|sed "s/\..*//"|xclip -selection clipboard %i<cr>
```

---

Vifm processes the [macros](https://vifm.info/manual.shtml#Command%20macros) before passing the
command to the shell. `%c` becomes the file name (properly escaped);
`%s` would also be substituted, thus `%%s` is needed so that
printf gets a `%s`. Likewise, `<cr>` is the "<kbd>Enter</kbd>
equivalent" and is required, otherwise the command whole simply
pops up in the command-line.

This has been tested. Even the exquisitely named file
`t*.a .<!e>&` passed the test, the clipboard gets `t*`.

If you want to remove everything after and including the *last*
dot (not the first), use `sed "s/\.[^.]*$//"`.

---

To display the copied string in the statusbar, repeat the command up to sed
and use the `%S` macro.

```
:nnoremap yn :!printf '%%s' %c|sed "s/\..*//"|xclip -selection clipboard %i<cr>:!printf '%%s' %c|sed "s/\..*//;s/$/ is yanked to clipboard/" %S<cr>
```